# Nvidia 820M problem on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics, nvidia-geforce

My computer is not being able to detect the Nvidia 820M Graphics Card.
When I run `lspci -k | grep -A 2 -i "VGA"` this is the output i get

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics (rev 09)
    DeviceName:  Onboard IGD
    Subsystem: Dell Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics
```

There is no mention of the Nvidia Graphics Card

Comment: This is a hardware problem, not a software problem.

Comment: It works fine in Windows